# Windows 7 starts with 1.5gb of ram missing, hindering minecraft memory usage

Tags: memory, minecraft, superfetch

I tried to search for an answer, but couldn't find one.  On my computer there's a lot of ram non-free and not shown in task manager under processes.

Minecraft requires a lot of memory.  I have 8 gigs.  I let it go as high as 4, but somehow windows is using up so much with something hidden that it gets to about 3 and windows tells me to close something cause I don't have enough memory.

Firefox uses up a half gig after long enough.

Is all this superfetch?  I don't really want to disable that, but I deserve to be able to use the damn ram I installed.

Comment: Is your memory *missing*, or is it simply *in use*?

Comment: If you asked questions elsewhere with the same attitude you are showing here (before my edit), I am not surprised if people were not very helpful. Anyway, could you show us a screenshot of the process manager showing how much RAM is used? What version of windows are you using, is it a 64bit one?

Comment: I haven't been asking questions anywhere with this attitude, the only time I do is when I try to search for an answer, and I see a lot of people with the same problem but no one wants to help and just says "that's how it's supposed to be, ram is supposed to be used at all times etc etc" when this is clearly not the case.  @DopeGhoti If it's in use, I can't find it.  And I am a superuser lol.

Comment: Run RAMMap and post a picture of RAMMAp here when you get the error again: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2010/08/13/introduction-to-the-new-sysinternals-tool-rammap.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is what type of graphics adapter does your computer have?  If you are consistently showing that you only have 6.5GB of your 8GB available, that sounds like your system is using shared memory (in other words system memory) for your graphics adapter, as opposed to it having dedicated memory.

Comment: It's a gtx 260, with 896MB ram built in.  Sorry for not providing computer specs in question.  Also have i5 processor, but I'm pretty sure this isn't it.